# Byte concatenation for SPI Transmit (STM32)

Tags: stm32, c, spi

I want to transmit data to EEPROM via SPI but I can not concatenate command bytes and data bytes. In my scenario, I need to transmit 3 bytes of command and 64 bytes of data. How can I send this data all together?

Comment: You should post your code, so people can give you a better answer. Also part numbers of the MCU and EEPROM would help.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to concatenate the data. Transmit the command then transmit the data and it will be fine.

If you use a chip select, do not deassert it between command and data, only after data has been sent.